# How to change numpy array to geotiff array without saving on computer?

Tags: python, display, gdal, geotiff, rasterio

I am using gdal.translate() to make the image but its saving the formed image on local machine, I don't want to save it anywhere in my local machine and use it on run time only without saving it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If even temp files are undesirable, consider using the rasterio library

Answer (score 0):

Use a `/vsimem/` filename - the dataset will exist only in a temporary in-memory filesystem. You will be able to access it as a normal file from GDAL until the process termination.

https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsimem-in-memory-files